# How does one insert a variable value into a "myCRED plugin shortcode

Tags: shortcode

Example:

```
[mycred_exchange from="mycred_default" to="mycred_usd" min= "0.00001" rate="8127"]
```

In this instance I would like to link the exchange rate (`rate="8127"`) to the actual market value of Bitcoin.

I have gone through a few articles but just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the shortcode as a string like this :

```
$rate = 2587.36;
$code = "[mycred_exchange from=\"mycred_default\" to=\"mycred_usd\" min=\"0.00001\" rate=\"$rate\"]";
```

and then, to execute the code

```
echo do_shortcode($code);
```

Comment: to use this plugin functions, try that  :   `$reponseJSON = CPCurrencyInfo::cp_convert_currency("BTC", ["EUR"]);
      $reponse = json_decode($reponseJSON, TRUE);      $rate = $reponse["EUR"];`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, the shortcode retreives the data but displays on my site as " [mycred_exchange from="mycred_default" to="mycred_usd" min="0.00001" rate="8.465E-5"] " instaed of displaying the "myCRED" exchange form.